# Why Java Swing JProgressBar is not working properly in Nimbu Look and Feel?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am working on one simple java project which traverses through the specified directory and finds the redundant files. Everything except one thing is working fine, I am using JProgressBar to show the status of directory spanning. It is working just fine with other look and feels but, when I set my favourite "Nimbus Look & Feel", the progress bar is not showing the fill color of progress. I set the progress bar to paint the string along. The string is showing up(3%, 5%...). I am new to look and feels in java.

Code I used to update the progress bar...

```
private synchronized void updateProgress(long length)
{
        prog = prog + (length/onePart);

        if(prog>100)
            prog = 100;

        addLog((int)prog + " % completed.");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progress.setValue((int)prog);
                progress.setString((int)prog+" %");
                progress.update(progress.getGraphics());
            }
        });
}
```

[image]

Comment: ???`progress.update(progress.getGraphics());`??? This confuses me to no end. What is this line supposed to accomplish? Also I suggest that you create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that uses a background thread with `Thread.sleep(...)` calls to simulate a long-running background process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I am new to stack over flow so, I was unable to post the sample pic. About the line, I went online and found this code for my project. I don't exactly know what it accomplishes. I thought it would update the gui. This exact code is working well in other look and feels ??

Comment: 1) Wherever you found that line of code, remember the site and make sure that you get no further advice from it and especially from whoever made that recommendation as it is completely misleading and potentially dangerous. 2) If you create an image and post a link to it, many of us can edit your post and add the image to your question. 3) I still strongly urge you to create a very small [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that doesn't do any file or directory manipulation, but just tries to us a progress bar so that we can test it and modify it.

Comment: I think these two images explain my problem. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_KnIEaA-nMSkZURnVPSElBeFE/edit?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_KnIEaA-nMUUc4T3lVNTV6OHM/edit?usp=sharing,

Comment: As a side note may be you are interested in this api [Progress Monitors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#monitors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I again suggest you create a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like the code below. In fact, please feel free to modify this code so that it reproduces your problem:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NimbusFoo extends JPanel {
   private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

   public NimbusFoo() {
      progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
      add(progressBar);
      add(new JButton(new StartAction("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
   }

   private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
      public StartAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         final JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
         btn.setEnabled(false);

         final SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            Random random = new Random();
            private long sleepTime = 200;
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
               int progress = 0;
               setProgress(progress);

               while (progress < 100) {
                  progress += random.nextInt(5);
                  progress = Math.min(100, progress);
                  setProgress(progress);
                  Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
               }
               return null;
            };
         };
         mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
               if ("progress".equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
                  progressBar.setValue(mySwingWorker.getProgress());
                  progressBar.setString(mySwingWorker.getProgress() + "%");
               }
               if ("state".equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
                  if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                     btn.setEnabled(true);
                  }
               }
            }
         });
         mySwingWorker.execute();
      };
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {

      try {
         for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      NimbusFoo mainPanel = new NimbusFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nimbus Fun");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 good example by guessing what OP is trying to do and in the way he has to do :P  , this is much simpler using a template like swingWorker that provide mechanism to update gui via the observer pattern as you shown

Comment: Thank you both. But there was no bug in the code at all. I set the height of progress bar so small, that there was no space for fill colour. I figured it out and increased its height. It works fine. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: @NogardBlack: 1) that is one reason why you should never set the heights, width or bounds of anything. Instead you should let the natural preferred sizes of your components and your layout managers do the sizing for you. 2) If this post helped in any way, consider up-voting it for the work done and effort given in order to try to help you. 3) There is no way anyone could guess what your problem was or be able to help you based on the data you posted. This is why I kept asking you to create and post a minimal example program. Please consider these suggestions for your future questions here.